# Pointwise convergence of $\frac{x^n}{1+x^n} $

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Is this sequence convergent or divergent? I first thought it was convergent due to pointwise limits existing at every value of $x$ but now im not sure wether or not I am right.

My sequence is $f_n(x)=\dfrac{x^n}{1+x^n} $ with $x \in [0,1]$.

How do I decide whether this sequence is convergent or divergent?

Comment: Are you asking for pointwise convergence or uniform convergence?

Comment: When you use the word "series" do you really mean the word "sequence"?  $\{f_{n}(x)\}$ is a sequence of functions, but it could also be that you're talking about $\sum \limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} f_{n}(x)$, which is a series.  We can talk about the convergence or divergence of both a sequence and a series, so which one are you asking about?

Comment: pointwise convergence

Comment: And it is a sequence

Comment: Hint: $0\le x^n/(1+x^n)\le x^n$.

Answer (score 1):

You may observe that
$$
0\leq f_n(x)=\frac{x^n}{1+x^n}\leq x^n, \quad x \in [0,1],
$$ giving, for $x \in [0,1]$,
$$f_n(x) \to
f(x)=\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if  $\,0\leq x<1,$} \\[2ex]
1/2, & \text{if $\,x=1.$}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: However doesnt the fact that the series is not continuous mean it wouldn't be convergent ??

Comment: @darren The pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions may not be continuous. This fact is one of the main points of exercises like this one.

Comment: For $x=1$, I was more thinking of $1/2$.

Comment: @Ian: Of course it can. Maybe you mean the *uniform* limit.

Comment: @AlexM. I said "may not", not "cannot". "May not" means it is possible that the thing doesn't happen.

Comment: @Ian: Oh, then you mean "might not", because "may not" means "is not allowed to". Anyway, I see your point.

Comment: @AlexM. This is one of those annoying contextual things in English. In a context where someone could be giving permission, "may" means "permission is given" and so "may not" means "permission is not given". But we also say things like "I may go to the store" when there is no relevant permission-giver, in which case it means essentially the same as "I might go to the store". At any rate, "might not" would have been clearer.

Comment: @Ian: I realized the ambiguity only after posting the comment. I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $x \in [0, 1)$, you have $x^n \to 0$ and thus $f_n(x) \to \dfrac 0 {1+0} = 0$. When $x=1$, you have $f_n(x) = \dfrac 1 2$. Therefore, $f_n \to f$ where $f = \left\{ \begin{matrix} 0, & x \in [0, 1), \\ \dfrac 1 2, & x = 1. \end{matrix}\right.$

Answer (score 0):

The question says:

> "I first thought it was convergent due to pointwise limits existing at every value of $x$".

That is precisely the meaning of the statement that $f_n$ converges **pointwise** as $n\to\infty$.

In comments, you wrote:

> However doesnt the fact that the series is not continuous mean it wouldn't be convergent ??

The discontinuous nature of the pointwise limit does not change the fact that it is the pointwise limit.

It does mean that the sequence does not converge **uniformly**.  **Uniform** convergence of $f_n$ to $g$ as $n\to\infty$ means
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup \{ |f_n(x) - g(x)| : x\in[0,1] \} = 0.
$$
That doesn't happen when $g$ is the pointwise limit.  And the uniform limit, if it exists, will always be the same as the pointwise limit.  Therefore, there is no function to which this sequence converges **uniformly**.

Comment: Thank you I see my mis-understading clearly now